# Процентное соотношение div-блоков

Tags: html, css

Нужно внутри дива поставить статичный див шириной 200px и динамический шириной 60% оставшегося места + 40%-й див в конце. Картинка:

[image]

Как сделать:

пытался так:

```
div 1 - width:100%; height:100%;
div 2 - width:200px;
div 3 - width:60%;
див 4 (пустота) - 40%
```

Но блоки создают страницу больше 100%. Откуда лишние проценты? Как будет правильнее?

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/71512/

Comment: Ну а чего вы хотите? 

Представим, что div1 шириной в 1000px, тогда div3, по заданным условиям будет 600px(или 60%), а div4 - 400px(или 40%). Т.е div3 вместе с div4 обладают 100%от родительского блока, от div1, а к ним еще и плюсуется div2, который фиксирован на 200px. В общей сложности получается div3+div2+div4=1200px. Если div1 задать overflow hidden, то правый из блоков обрежется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tLuhx0tk/ вот пример накидал, один из вариантов размещения таких блоков

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант https://codepen.io/yamich/pen/ExYXQGP

```
HTML

<div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="div-200"></div>
    <div class="div-60"></div>
    <div class="div-end"></div>
</div>
```

```
CSS

div {
    height: 100px;
}
.div-200 {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.div-60 {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: green;
}
.div-end {
    float: left;
    width: calc(40% - 200px);
    background-color: blue;
}
```